# What is the sense of Reduce part of Map-Reduce indexes?

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I don't use Reduce part of my indexes. Instead of that I use Where clause for my Map index queries. What is the difference between these two approaches: to use Reduce part of the Map-Reduce index or use Where clause on Map index?

My guess, please correct me if I am wrong. In the case of Map-Reduce index your store less data as part of index so queries are more efficient. But if you need to make several queries on some document type, it could be more efficient to use one Map index (with different Where conditions) instead of several Map-Reduce indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce is computations and aggregations. Map is selecting the data for the computations/aggregations. the where clause is typically stored with the mapping.

and just be careful you are prematurely attempting to create efficient queries. IMO it's better to have many context specific queries, than a few general purpose queries.

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't be filtering on the where clause in 90% of the cases in a Map index. You should do the filtering during the query, it is _really_ fast.